# Access VBA equivalent to a C# List<T>

Tags: c#, ms-access, vba, interop

I have a COM-visible object written in C# that accepts a list of string arrays. Could I send a Collection of string arrays from Access 2000 to this object and it work? If not, then what is the best way to send multiple string arrays to my C# object from Access 2000?

Comment: Note that Access uses VBA.  Which is very close but not quite the same as VB6.

Comment: Oh ok. I just started programming in Access not too long ago. So this is all still kinda confusing to me. I tested out my COM-visible object code in a separate project and called it from a Main method. It worked with a List of string arrays passed to it, but since I have been trying to call it from Access, I have had no luck.

Comment: Oops, bad day. I thought I was in the text box when I hit enter.

Answer (score 4):

You can't marshal generics but using Collection on the VB6 side is a workable solution.  Effectively convert your List to a standard collection.

Here's something that elaborates more: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/netclasslistvb6.aspx?display=Print

Comment: I'm an experienced Access programmer, but I can't see how the cited URL answers the question. Can you draw it out a bit?

Comment: The question was phrased incorrectly, referring to VB6 when the asker meant VBA. The asker clarified this by [posting a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516325/vba-equivalent-to-listt-in-c). I edit this question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of com add in work on VBA and vb.net - I find replacing a List (of T) in vb.net with an arraylist works very well in VBA, not all the properties expose exactly the same way in Access, but you can work around it.