# VBA Equivalent to List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, vba, interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB6 equivalent to a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497982/vb6-equivalent-to-a-listt)

> **Duplicate of:**
>
> [Access VBA equivalent to a `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497982/access-vba-equivalent-to-a-listt)

I posted this question with the wrong information before, so I am reposting it in the hopes of getting a correct answer. I have a COM-visible object written in C# that accepts a list of string arrays. Could I send a Collection of string arrays from Access 2000 to this object and it work? If not, then what is the best way to send multiple string arrays to my C# object from Access 2000?

Comment: Next time you post a question with wrong information, please **edit the question** to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, COM has no concept of generics; so you won't have any luck trying to make something out of a `List<string[]>`.

Why don't you just add an overload to your C# method to accept a `string[][]` (a jagged array of strings)? That should be doable from VBA, unless I'm mistaken.

I apologize if this answer is way off the mark; I don't have MS Office installed on this machine and am basically answering based on my limited knowledge of VBA and COM interop. But I thought the jagged array suggestion might at least nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think VB6 has jagged arrays. I think you mean Multidimensional arrays, which VB6 does have

Comment: @icemanind, VB has jagged arrays (type variant).